# Install Openerp/Odoo development environment ubuntu 14.04lts

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, ubuntu-14.04, openerp-7

I'm Working on my Graduation project and it should be an Open source ERP system for my University,so I start my search for open source erp tools and I foucd that odoo is the best.

I need to develop a module for my University with python and I'm trying to install the development environment but no luck tell now.

I follow that tut : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaeOq4rbRMw
to install it but I have that errors in my eclipse

```
2014-12-02 21:40:42,158 15166 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0
2014-12-02 21:40:42,158 15166 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/addons
2014-12-02 21:40:42,158 15166 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-12-02 21:40:42,158 15166 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-12-02 21:40:42,158 15166 INFO ? openerp: database user: mostafa
2014-12-02 21:40:42,159 15166 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web: module not found
2014-12-02 21:40:42,159 15166 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2014-12-02 21:40:42,159 15166 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web
2014-12-02 21:40:42,159 15166 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web
2014-12-02 21:40:42,160 15166 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web_kanban: module not found
2014-12-02 21:40:42,160 15166 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web_kanban
2014-12-02 21:40:42,160 15166 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web_kanban
2014-12-02 21:40:42,160 15166 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web_kanban`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/home/mostafa/workspace/odoo_7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web_kanban
2014-12-02 21:40:42,165 15166 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2014-12-02 21:40:42,165 15166 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8077
2014-12-02 21:42:59,563 15166 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2014 21:42:59]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-12-02 21:42:59,646 15166 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2014 21:42:59] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-12-02 21:42:59,699 15166 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [Dec/2014 21:42:59] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
```

and when i start my browser with `localhost:8077` "My port"

it says : No handler found.
I wish you could help me, and offer me good tut to start learning how to use that great tool and develop on it.

I have downloaded Openerp 7.0 from GitHub and I go with the video step by step.

regards.

Comment: Why don't you try out Odoo V8 or Odoo V9? They've changed so much for us developers, IMO the better way. The new API is way more comfortable and the documentation is getting better and better

Answer (score 0):

Actually those module are updated in ubuntu 14.04 because it is not working in ubuntu 14.04, download those module or copy those modules form ubuntu 12.04 and replace with existing modules then it will work.
**Replace these modules**
**werkzeug**
**Werkzeug-0.8.1.egg-info****